# Django: AJAX and path params

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I am trying to figure out how to communicate variables a particular js file that makes an AJAX request in Django.

Say we have an url with a path param that maps to a particular view:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', TemplateView.as_view('post.html'))
```

And then the `post.html` includes a script that performs an AJAX request to fetch the post as JSON:

```
post.html

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/post.js"></script>
<div id="post-container"></div>
```

This could be the js file. Let's say we do it this way because the post (as JSON) needs to be used in a js plugin to display it in a particular fancy manner.

```
post.js

$.ajax({
   url: '/post/??post_id??',
   contentType: 'application/json'
})
.done(function(post_data) {
    togglePlugin(post_data);
});
```

My main concern is how to figure out what `post_id` is from the js file in order to make the appropriate call.

How are these parts usually connected in Django? The parts I am talking about are urls, path params, views and ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get urls from your template you should use `{% url %}` template tag, for that you should add a name to your url:

`url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', TemplateView.as_view('post.html'), name='my_name)`

then in your can template call that url in this way `{% url 'my_name' object.pk  %}`  see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for more.

when you work with different file for your js, and you want to pass django variables, you should declare a `<script>` before import the js file, and there declare your variable:

```
<srcipt>var foo={{django_var}}</script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/post.js"></script>
```

and then use the variable `foo` in the js.

Comment: If I want the url generated by `{% url ... %}` to be stored in a js variable so I can perform the ajax request to that url, how could I do it? I tried `var url = {% url 'my_name' var1 var2 }%` but I got a js error.

Comment: Ok you're not answering but I found the answer myself, it's: `var url = "{% url 'my_name' var1 var2 }%";` (wrapping it with double quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a post_id variable to django template.
However if you don't want it to "hurt", put your .js code (script) in you html file, rendered by django. So you can use django template tags.

For example:

```
        var url = "/post/{{post_id}}";
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                some_field: field_data,
                some_other_field: field_data
            },
            success: function(data) {
                do_something();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                do_somethin();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this the standard way? Placing the script directly in the template instead of in a separate js file sounds like a bad practice.

Comment: Only if you will parse JS like a template. And this is a bad approach. If you need to have it in separate way, you have to "hide" somewhere your post_id variable. In some button / form field, which css is set to hidden. So then you can fetch is with jQuery or smth.

Comment: Yes I thought of that and it seems like a terrible, hacky idea.

Comment: Yes, that is why Im just placing my ajax request inside my template.